# Error: $(document).ready is not a function

Tags: ajax, cakephp, prototypejs

I understand this question has been asked multiple times on various sites and forums however the context has mostly been jquery. In my case, **I am not using jquery at all** though I am using CakePHP 1.3 with **prototype** and **scriptoculous**. I am trying to make Ajax pagination work using default Js helper however every time I load the page, I get the error below in error console

```
Error: $(document).ready is not a function
```

Any idea what's wrong here.

Comment: Does prototype use the same method to check if a page has been loaded...? That looks identical to jQuery's, and if you're not including the jQuery library in your page then it will throw that error.

Comment: I am not really sure of that since I am not much familiar with prototype (or any other JS library for that matter). I am using the default setup of CakePHP without any tweaks. Though I ready somewhere while searching for my answer that syntax of JQuery and prototype is similar. Not sure if it make any sense here.

Comment: second that. Is this an exclusive jQuery check?

Comment: Noup, my app has nothing to do with jQuery. Based on the answers received so far I have another question - Do I need to modify prototype script? I haven't modified or tweaked the script at all and using the freshly downloaded latest version so why should this happen in first place? Moreover as per the official Cake tutorial, it should work out of the box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems (after some googeling) that the syntax to use in prototype is `document.observe('dom:loaded', fn);`

http://www.prototypejs.org/api/document/observe

Answer (score 0):

In prototype, I think you can use

```
document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
    // Do initialization here
});
```

for performing the initialization tasks.